# What is more standard shortening for "regular expression", "regex" or "regexp"?

Tags: naming, regular-expressions

I want to know what is more standard way to call regular expression in short way. I have seen both, regex and regexp.

Google says regex has almost 2 as much hits that regexp, but it depends on way I search it (when I add "regular expression" after the word, "regex" becomes "regex regular expression", the result is differend). And on stackexchange there is regex tag. :)

What is more proper way to shorten it?

Perhaps it does not matter. :) But thanks for answer.

Comment: How to shorten the word "regular expressions" isn't really a constructive question that's going to have a correct answer or provide anything more than a poll of people's preferences.

Comment: @Mark -- I do not see why this question was closed as "not meeting the guidelines". I can tick off the guidelines, and IMO it meets most of them. For instance, it is asked in an impartial tone, it invites discussion of why (as seen in some of the excellent answers), it invites sharing of experiences, and it is not merely "mindless fun".

Comment: @Jay I encourage you to take a look at the FAQ, specifically under the section on [what not to ask](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) and particularly the part where it says to avoid asking questions where every answer is equally valid and there's no actual problem to be solved. If you have any additional concerns or questions, feel free to ask about it on [our meta discussion site](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Regexp is kind of old, IMHO.

Answer (score 13):

There's no right or wrong abbreviation here. It'll mostly be influenced by what APIs you're working with:

#### It's Regex!

- [java.util.regex](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/package-summary.html) in Java
- [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) in .NET
- [regex](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Perl-compatible-regular-expressions.html) in GLib

#### It's Regexp!

- [Regexp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Regexp.html) in Ruby
- [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) in JavaScript
- [QRegExp](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qregexp.html) in Qt

#### It's something else entirely!

- [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) in Python
- [preg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php) in PHP
- [NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in iOS/Mac OS
- [//](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) in Perl ;)

The fact that Jeffrey Friedl, author of the excellent [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596528126), lives at [regex.info](http://regex.info/) is good enough for me: I tend to call them regexes. But I keep this close at hand just in case I change my mind later...

```
s/\bregex\b/$&p/gi;
```

Comment: It's Rexexp in perl. Proof: Execute this one-liner: `perl -le 'print ref(qr/re/)'`. Or maybe its regex? "regex" wins out over "regexp" by a wide margin in `man perlre`.

Comment: It's **regex**, FTW!

Comment: This is a minor nit, but regular expressions aren't called "preg" in PHP.  preg is the prefix for one set of regex functions that use the PCRE engine.

Comment: @MattBelanger And they're not "called" `//` in Perl either. :) It was a general point about the various abbreviations or other conventions used between languages.

Comment: @Mark Whitaker I blame posting at 6:30AM, before I've had my coffee :)

Comment: Mastering Regular Expressions was a great read!  I recommend that book.

Answer (score 11):

As some indication - there's a `Regex` class in .NET and `regex` package in Java; not `Regexp`. Two fairly large 'ecosystems'. This by itself means more to me than as if some committee, somewhere, decided it this way or that way.

Comment: In Javascript, it's RegExp

Answer (score 9):

There is no standard that dictates this. As to what is more common, Google says *regex* vs. *regexp* by some 13.8 vs 9.8 million finds.

Answer (score 6):

**Regex** is much more common, and you might get an odd glance or two if you say **Regexp**.

Comment: Unless, of course, you said it to a Rubyist. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I have never before this thread seen it shortened to `regexp` and always seen it as `regex`. Just to add to the list, the new C++ Standard has `<regex>`, not `<regexp>`.

Answer (score 1):

what's more standard depends on the predominant language of the folks you're talking to, I would argue. Correct above about `Regex` in .NET and Java, but Ruby uses the `Regexp` class for regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is more morphological. Consider yourself as the first person who wants to provide an abbreviation for this **concept** (Definitely regex or regexp both come from somewhere and haven't been with us since Adam), and you know that it should come from **regular** and **expression**.

My dictionary tells me that **reg.** is an abbreviated form of **regularly** and **exp.** is a shorthand of **express**. Thus if you want to follow the rules of abbreviations, **REGEXP** seems more structural. However, forming new words (neologism as they call it) is not always straight and often is done by people who are not linguists. Considering these issues, to make a name which with a more aesthetically appealing pronunciation, you can create **REGEX**.

Also as a note, StackExchange editor considers regex as wrong spell, while regexp is fine :)

Comment: SE editor doesn't have Spell Check.